# Authorization for Contacts API across domain access using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-contacts-api

I am working in a Google Apps Script web app using Contacts API v3, to access all user's contacts within the domain.

I have no problems so far with Contacts API requests, but I have no idea yet on how to get authorization across the domain to access any user's contacts (other than me).

I have tried OAuth domain key from cpanel - advanced tools, with no results so far. I got "Request failed for returned code 403 (Forbidden)" when trying with other users within the domain

Thanks in advance, Fausto

EDIT-1 (Mar.05) I'm closer now, but need a bit of help

I have combined 2LO (2-legged OAuth) with oauth_signature and signing request, but still getting Error 401 (Client Error)!!1. This is the sample code I am working with now.

```
function test_xOAuth() {
  // OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET from GApps: control panel > advanced tools > Manage OAuth domain key 
  var domain = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail().split("@")[1];
  var xuser = 'fausto@thexs.ca';
  var method = "GET";
  var baseUrl = "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/groups/default/full";
  var timestamp = getTimestamp();
  var paramsJson = {
    oauth_consumer_key : domain,
    oauth_nonce : getNonce(timestamp),
    oauth_signature_method : "HMAC-SHA1",
    oauth_timestamp : timestamp,
    oauth_version : "1.0"
  };
  var paramsStringArray =  [];
  for (var k in paramsJson) paramsStringArray.push(k + '="' + paramsJson[k] + '"');
  var paramsString = paramsStringArray.join("&") + '&xoauth_requestor_id=' + xuser;
  var signatureBaseString = method +"&"+ encodeURIComponent(baseUrl) +"&"+ encodeURIComponent(paramsString);
  var signatureBytes = Utilities.computeHmacSha256Signature(signatureBaseString, OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET);
  var signature = Utilities.base64Encode(signatureBytes);
  var xoauthString = 'OAuth ' + paramsStringArray.join(",") + ',oauth_signature="' + signature + '"';
  var options = {
    method : method,
    headers : {"Authorization" : xoauthString}
  }
  var url = baseUrl + '?xoauth_requestor_id=' + 'fausto@thexs.ca';
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  var responseHeader = response.getHeaders();
  var responseText = response.getContentText();
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(responseText);
}

var getTimestamp = function(){
  return (Math.floor((new Date()).getTime() / 1000)).toString()
}

var getNonce = function(timestamp){
  return timestamp + Math.floor( Math.random() * 100000000)
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help !! Fausto

Comment: not sure it is interesting for you but have you seen the [new library](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/new-connectors-to-google-services/profiles-services) brought by Romain Vialard ?

Comment: very interest indeed, already had a look at it. However, that is for profiles api that live at the domain level, and what I need is for contacts api that would need 2-legged access to work across all domain user's contacts ... I guess (not sure of anything at this point)

Comment: Instead of the domain cpanel domain key, use [Google APIs Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/b/0/) to setup an API Access profile which will generate a Simple API Access token.

Comment: I got excited with your suggestion @Jonathon , however when I created a new project at the API console, I couldn't find Contacts API among the available services to activate... Am I missing something?

Comment: it doesn't need specific activation (i think i recall that it used to) but this is the best way of managing app specific access tokens

Comment: Hi @Jonathon it didn't work that way either, only for the user who registered the App, but not across all domain users. Also, I cannot get and API key because there is no Contacts API service available to use in the console. I know it's possible, though I haven't found my way there after many hours of searching and trying

Comment: I'll give it some more thought

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should properly URL-encode all parameters before you calculate signature.
Second, strip the quotes, you don't really need them, especially in the base string.
Third, you should use signature method you're specifying i.e. HMAC-SHA1. And last but not least, despite you're not using OAuth token you still need to include '&' in the encryption key.

Here's the code that works properly:

```
  var OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET = 'you secret goes here';
  var domain = 'domain.tld';
  var username = 'test.user';
  var xuser = encodeURIComponent(username+'@'+domain);
  var method = "GET";
  var baseUrl = "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/groups/default/full";
  var timestamp = Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000);
  var paramsJson = {
    oauth_consumer_key : domain,
    oauth_nonce : timestamp,
    oauth_signature_method : "HMAC-SHA1",
    oauth_timestamp : timestamp,
    oauth_version : "1.0"
  };
  var paramsStringArray =  [];
  for (var k in paramsJson) paramsStringArray.push(k + '=' + encodeURIComponent(paramsJson[k]));
  var paramsString = paramsStringArray.join("&") + "&xoauth_requestor_id="+xuser;
  var signatureBaseString = method +"&"+ encodeURIComponent(baseUrl) +"&"+ encodeURIComponent(paramsString);
  var signatureBytes = Utilities.computeHmacSignature(Utilities.MacAlgorithm.HMAC_SHA_1, signatureBaseString, OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET+'&');

  var signature = encodeURIComponent(Utilities.base64Encode(signatureBytes));
  var xoauthString = 'OAuth ' + paramsStringArray.join(", ") + ', oauth_signature="' + signature + '"';

  var options = {
    method : method,
    headers : {authorization: xoauthString}
  }
  var url = baseUrl + '?xoauth_requestor_id=' + xuser;
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
```

Comment: thanks a lot, you have put my feet into the right path... WHAT an answer !!

Answer (score 0):

I have not performed the access to contacts like you mention here but I have manage to perform a similar action to act as a domain user and access the users Google drive, The one limiting factor to this was that to be able to do what you are trying to do is that you have to be a super administrator for you Google domain and the access level i had to use was trough URL Requests and REST API, You might also what to have a look at [Google Domain Shared Contacts API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/domain-shared-contacts/) to be able to manage your shared contacts in a Google domain and leave everyone's personal contacts to be managed by them self

Comment: Could you share how to manage the 2-legged authentication in the Drive  API case (assuming Contacts API would be similar)? // Shared Contacts doesn't need 2-legged Auth and it's not suitable for this requeriment @user2111108